# angular - print ng-table title dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am stuck at a point where i want to print the sub-heading title's dynamically using ng-table, header should be type1 type2 type3 and Details must be main head, subtype value must be sub-heading in details, please see picture attached below[image]

any help is much aprreciated.

Comment: Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/rLOWTCxXKyhKM2suxIBA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
https://plnkr.co/edit/gypa0JDAZqhNwWcRQK93?p=preview

```
            <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
              <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
              <table ng-table="tableParams">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3"></td>
                  <td colspan="{{detailsCount}}" style="text-align:center">Details</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="i in dataObject">
                  <td title="'Type1'">{{i.type1}}</td>
                  <td title="'Type2'">{{i.type2}}</td>
                  <td title="'Type3'">{{i.type3}}</td>
                  <td ng-repeat="d in i.details" ng-init="detailsColCount(i.details)">{{d.subTypeCode}}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </body>

            $scope.detailsCount = 0;
            $scope.detailsColCount = function(details){
                  if (details.length > $scope.detailsCount) {
                    $scope.detailsCount = details.length;
                  }
                };
```

Comment: thank you for spending time on this, but i am more concerned about headings, like

Comment: like type1 type2 type3 a b c d with A B C D a1 b1 c1 d1 as record underneath, obivously 'Details' heading on top of a b c d.